# How does Guilloché pattern inhibit counterfeiting?

Tags: paper-money, counterfeiting

[I was unsure whether to post this in Money.SE, GraphicDesign.SE, or Security.SE, I finally chose Money.]

It's common to include [Guilloché patterns](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GuillochePattern.html) on banknotes, security certificates, and passports to improve security against couterfeiting. I find it hard to believe that modern imaging and printing technology has problems reproducing any image they're given. Is this still an effective deterrent, or is it mostly a legacy of past technology? If it still works, how?

Comment: There are limitations specifically designed into many scanners and printers which recognize certain patterns used in currency and refuse to accurately replicate them. Also, increasingly, there are details that are beyond the resolution or most commercially available equipment. I don't know whether these particular patterns are still effective or not, and if I did know I'm not really inclined to say.

Comment: Most modern notes have other antiforgery measures these days, from things embedded in the paper to holograms to color-changing inks to you-name-it.  That doesn't mean the older measures aren't worth continuing to use; each layer of security adds to the others.

Comment: I imagine that there's a certain amount of "people *expect* banknotes to have such patterns", no matter if they are no longer the primary security feature they once were

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I find it hard to believe that modern imaging and printing technology has problems reproducing any image they're given.

Just because the technology exists doesn't mean your average forger has access to it. Effective forgeries probably involve using the same/similar paper stock and printing process as the original, rather than a scanner and inkjet printer. Creating printing plates isn't trivial and these patterns are one of many [security features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_printing?wprov=sfla1) being used.

> A geometric lathe was used for making ornamental patterns on the plates used in printing bank notes and postage stamps. It is sometimes called a guilloché lathe. It was developed early in the nineteenth century when efforts were introduced to combat forgery, and is an adaptation of an ornamental turning lathe. **The lathe was able to generate intersecting and interlacing patterns of fine lines in various shapes, which were almost impossible to forge by hand-engraving.** They were used by many national mints.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_lathe